# Should I Thread.Sleep for a hours or there are more smarter way?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have to update some data every 1 hour in a Thread. I put the Method-checker into a new Thread

```
if ((time_now - last_update) < 3600)
            Thread.Sleep(3600 * 1000);
```

But I feel like this isn't correct. Maybe there is an elegant and inexpensive way to check for updates every hour without `Thread.Sleep` in C#?

Comment: I feel as though this should be scheduled by something in your OS --- look in to cron jobs. Doesn't seem like you would want to leave a program running for an hour. Plus if the program closes the job stops.

Comment: Yeah, use the Windows Task Schedule for this.  Don't make a thread sleep for hours.  That's wasteful.

Comment: Also it's always possible to use async calls and possibly a timer but I think preferably schedule it by OS

Comment: Use timer if its c# to get event fired based on time elapsed

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: i don't want to use OS-dependent functions, the program loads item-list from a third-party server and work with an items, but the items often updates in a random time. Item list should be updated twice per day or twenty-times per day. I just need to load a new items if they will be available

Comment: I usually block using WaitOne.  See msdn : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58195swd(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Think about what you would do in real life. Threads are workers. If you had a job to do every hour would you hire a worker and instruct them to sleep while they weren't working? Or would you give an existing worker an alarm clock and say "when the clock rings, do this job"?

Comment: @EricLippert, Yeah, when we talk about thread pools, we talk about "worker threads;" but that's a misnomer.  Threads don't actually do the work.  The CPUs are the real workers.  The program is the instruction book that describes how to do the work, and each thread merely describes the state of a different job-in-progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about running your pulling method every fixed time:

```
var startTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero;
var periodTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);

var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
{
    YourPullingMethod();
}, null, startTimeSpan, periodTimeSpan);
```

Answer (score 1):

sleep should not be use. It is unreliable and can not be canceled; it is also blocking

you can do something like the following.

```
object waitTimeOut = new object();

lock (waitTimeOut) 
{ 
      Monitor.Wait(waitTimeOut, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3600 * 1000)); 
}
```

or

```
 TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3600 * 1000);
 t.Wait(ts)
```

Or with the low frequence you the other comments are good about using a cron job; and would be much more suitable to what you are doing

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the [`System.Threading.Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) class (or the other timers, use the one that is best suited for you).